# Expandir estrutura do MVC e modularizar por arquivos?

Tags: php, mvc

Estou tentando entender o padrão `MVC` e criei um exemplo com `CRUD` de usuários (com login), mas não sei se é a melhor maneira que eu criei.

Segue algumas páginas e o link pra download do projeto:

**index.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Leonardo Vilarinho
 * Date: 10/03/2016
 * Time: 00:55
 */

// include da camada Controller
require_once 'controller/ControllerLogin.php';



// Se variáveis de sessão tiverem ativas então já fez o login
if(isset($_SESSION['usuario']) and isset($_SESSION['id']))
{
    // define ato como listar-usuarios (primeira página apos login)
    $_GET['ato'] = (isset($_GET['ato'])) ? $_GET['ato'] : "listar-usuarios" ;
}
// se login não tiver sido feito
else
{
    // o ato será entrar
    $_GET['ato'] = "entrar";
}

//instancia uma nova classe Controller (do arquivo ControllerLogin ) 
$controller = new ControllerLogin();

//chama método do controller
$controller->requerir();
```

**ControllerLogin.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Leonardo Vilarinho
 * Date: 10/03/2016
 * Time: 00:56
 */

// include em camada model
require_once 'model/ModelLogin.php';

class ControllerLogin
{
    // variavel para ser a camada model
    private $model = NULL;

    // metodo contrutor, sempre que a classe ControllerLogin for criada ele executará esse metodo
    public function __construct()
    {
        //instancia uma classe da camada Model
        $this->model = new ModelLogin();
    }

    // método para encaminhar ação do usuário
    public function requerir()
    {
        // pega o get do link (exemplo index.php?ato=entrar) ato é a ação e entrar é o valor da ação
        $ato = (isset($_GET['ato'])) ? $_GET['ato'] : NULL;
        try
        {
            // verifica e chama metrodo para fazer ação selecionada
            if(!$ato or $ato == "entrar")
            {
                $this->fazerLogin();
            }
            else if($ato == "listar-usuarios")
            {
                $this->listarUsuarios();
            }
            else if($ato == "novo-usuario")
            {
                $this->novoUsuario();
            }
            else if($ato == "editar-usuario")
            {
                $this->editarUsuario();
            }
            else if($ato == "apagar-usuario")
            {
                $this->apagarUsuario();
            }
            else if($ato == "sair")
            {
                $this->sairSistema();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception $ex)
        {

        }

    }

    // método como um goto, para ir para uma página especifica
    private function irPara($pagina)
    {
        header("Location:".$pagina);
    }

    // método para o ato entrar
    private function fazerLogin()
    {
        // titulo da página
        $titulo = "Login MVC";

        // se formuĺário de login foi enviado (quando usuário clica em Entrar no login)
        if(isset($_POST['login-requerido']))
        {
            try
            {
                // cria uma variavel login para armazenar o resultado do metodo preparaLogin do model
                // aqui ele chama o métolo preparaLogin do arquivo ModelLogin passando os dados informados pelo usuario
                $login = $this->model->preparaLogin($_POST['nome'], $_POST['senha']);

                // se login for true (foi validado)
                if($login)
                {
                    // ele vai para a página com o ato de listar usuarios
                    $this->irPara("index.php?ato=listar-usuarios");
                }
                else
                {
                    // define um erro
                    $erro = "Usuário ou senha inválido(a).";
                }
            }
            catch(ValidationException $ex)
            {
                $erro = $ex->pegarErros();
            }
        }
        // inclue (escreve) arquivo entrar.php na página atual
        include 'view/entrar.php';
    }

    // método para o ato listar-usuarios
    private function listarUsuarios()
    {
        // define titulo da página
        $titulo = "Listagem de Usuários";
        try
        {
            // cria uma variavel lista para pegar o retorno do metodo listarTodos de model "usuarios" é a tabela do banco
            $lista = $this->model->listarTodos("usuarios");

            // se lista tiver vazia ou nao foi declarada
            if(empty($lista) or !$lista)
            {
                // define um erro
                $erro = "Sem usuários";
            }
        }
        catch(ValidationException $ex)
        {
            $erro = $ex->pegarErros();
        }

        // inclue (escreve) arquivo listar-usuarios.php na página atual
        include 'view/listar-usuarios.php';
    }

    // método para o ato novo-usuario
    private function novoUsuario()
    {
        // define titulo da página
        $titulo = "Adicionar Usuário";

        // se usuario clicou no botao Criar do formulario
        if(isset($_POST['novousuario-requerido']))
        {
            try
            {
                // cria uma variavel cadastro para armazenar o resultado do metodo preparaUsuarioNovo do model
                // aqui ele chama o métolo preparaUsuarioNovo do arquivo ModelLogin passando os dados informados pelo usuario
                $cadastro = $this->model->preparaUsuarioNovo($_POST['nome'], $_POST['senha']);

                // se fez o cadastro de usuário com sucesso
                if($cadastro)
                {
                    // volta para a página de listagem
                    $this->irPara("index.php?ato=listar-usuarios");
                }
                else
                {
                    // define um erro
                    $erro = "Houve um erro ao gravar o usuário.";
                }
            }
            catch(ValidationException $ex)
            {
                $erro = $ex->pegarErros();
            }
        }

        // inclue (escreve) arquivo novo-usuario.php na página atual
        include 'view/novo-usuario.php';
    }

    // método para o ato editar-usuario
    private function editarUsuario()
    {
        // define um titulo
        $titulo = "Editar Usuário";

        // pega id que está no link (index.php?ato=editar-usuario&id=4) id é 4
        $id = (int) $_GET['id'];

        // pesquisa usuario a ser editado pelo id e coloca em $usuario
        $usuario = $this->model->preparaUsuarioId($id);

        // se formulario de editar-usuario foi enviado
        if(isset($_POST['editarusuario-requerido']))
        {
            try
            {
                // chama método do model que edita um usuario
                $edicao = $this->model->preparaUsuarioEditar($_POST['id'], $_POST['nome'], $_POST['senha']);

                //se editou com sucesso
                if($edicao)
                {
                    // volta para listar usuarios
                    $this->irPara("index.php?ato=listar-usuarios");
                }
                else
                {
                    //define um erro
                    $erro = "Houve um erro ao editar o usuário.";
                }
            }
            catch(ValidationException $ex)
            {
                $erro = $ex->pegarErros();
            }
        }
        // inclue (escreve) arquivo editar-usuario.php na página atual
        include 'view/editar-usuario.php';
    }

    // método para o ato apagar-usuario
    private function apagarUsuario()
    {
        // titulo da página
        $titulo = "Editar Usuário";
        // pega id que esta no link " href="index.php?ato=apagar-usuario&id={$lista[$item]['id']}" "
        $id = (int) $_GET['id'];
        try
        {
            // chama metodo de apagar na camada model
            $tentativa = $this->model->preparaUsuarioApagar($id);

            // se apagou
            if($tentativa)
            {
                // vai para listagem
                $this->irPara("index.php?ato=listar-usuarios");
            }
            else
            {
                // exibe um erro
                $erro = "Houve um erro ao apagar o usuário.";
            }
        }
        catch(ValidationException $ex)
        {
            $erro = $ex->pegarErros();
        }
    }

    // método para o ato sair
    private function sairSistema()
    {
        // destroi variaveis de sessão
        unset($_SESSION['id']);
        unset($_SESSION['usuario']);
        // destroi sessao
        session_destroy();
        //vai para página de login
        $this->irPara("index.php?ato=entrar");
    }
}
```

**ModelLogin.php**

```
<?php

/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Leonardo Vilarinho
 * Date: 10/03/2016
 * Time: 01:10
 */

// include na biblioteca de CRUD
require_once 'libs/crud.php';

// inicia sessao
session_start();

class ModelLogin
{
    // variavel privada para chamar o crus
    private $crud = NULL;

    // metodo contrutor, sempre que a classe ModelLogin for criada ele executará esse metodo
    public function __construct()
    {
        // instancia um novo crud
        $this->crud = new CRUD();
    }

    // método que pega nome e senha do login
    public function preparaLogin($nome, $senha)
    {
        // aqui tem a validação dos campos (de tamanho etc)

        // retorna o resultado do método efetua login
        return $this->efetuaLogin($nome, $senha);
    }

    // metodo que verifica login (pega dados no banco e compara com os recebidos)
    private function efetuaLogin($nome, $senha)
    {
        try
        {
            // chama o metodo consult do crud na tabela usuarios onde a coluna usuario é igual nome
            // e armazena em usuario
            $usuario = $this->crud->consult("usuarios", "*", "usuario = {$nome}");

            // se o nome digitado for igual a coluna 'usuario' do primeiro resultado da consulta
            // e o a senha equivale a criptografada do banco
            if($nome == $usuario[0]['usuario'] and password_verify($senha, $usuario[0]['senha']))
            {
                // cria variaveis de sessao (que sao destuidas somente quando o navegadore fecha)
                $_SESSION['id'] = $usuario[0]['id'];
                $_SESSION['usuario'] = $usuario[0]['usuario'];

                return true;
            }
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch(CRUDException $ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // método que pega a tabela a ser listada
    public function listarTodos($tabela)
    {
        // retorna resultado da execução
        return $this->executarConsulta($tabela);
    }

    // método para consultar em uma tabela
    private function executarConsulta($tabela)
    {
        try
        {
            // retorna um array com o resultado da pesquisa de todas as colunas (*)
            return $resultado = $this->crud->consult($tabela, "*");
        }
        catch(CRUDException $ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // método que pega dados para criar um novo usuario
    public function preparaUsuarioNovo($nome, $senha)
    {
        // retorna resultado do insert
        return $this->cadastraUsuario($nome, $senha);
    }

// metodo que cadastro usuario no banco
    private function cadastraUsuario($nome, $senha)
    {
        try
        {
            // consulta no banco se tem um usuario com o mesmo nome 
            $verifica = $this->crud->consult("usuarios", "*", "usuario = {$nome}");

            // se nao tiver encontrado um usuario igual
            if(empty($verifica) or $verifica == null)
            {
                // insere novo usuario
                $this->crud->insert
                (
                    "usuarios",
                    array("usuario", "senha"),
                    array($nome, password_hash($senha, PASSWORD_DEFAULT))
                );
                return true;
            }
            // se usuario ja tiver cadastrado
            else
            {
                return false;
            }
        }
        catch(CRUDException $ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // metodo que pega id do usuario a ser editado (para pegar os dados dele e colocar na pagina de edição)
    public function preparaUsuarioId($id)
    {
        // retorna resultado da procura
        return $this->procuraUsuarioId($id);
    }

    // procura um usuario por id
    private function procuraUsuarioId($id)
    {
        try
        {
            // $consulta  vai receber um array com os dados daquele usuario
            $consulta = $this->crud->consult("usuarios", "*", "id = {$id}");

            // retorna o array ou false se nao achou usuario
            return (!empty($consulta)) ? $consulta : false;

        }
        catch(CRUDException $ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // pega novas dados do usuario a ser editado
    public function preparaUsuarioEditar($id, $nome, $senha)
    {
        // retorna o resultado da edição
        return $this->editarUsuario($id, $nome, $senha);
    }

    // edita usuario
    private function editarUsuario($id, $nome, $senha)
    {
        try
        {
            // retorna true ou false se editou ou nao o usuario
            return $this->crud->update
                (
                    "usuarios",
                    array("usuario", "senha"),
                    array($nome, password_hash($senha, PASSWORD_DEFAULT)),
                    "id = {$id}"
                );
        }
        catch(CRUDException $ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    // pega id do usuario a ser apagado
    public function preparaUsuarioApagar($id)
    {
        return $this->apagarUsuario($id);
    }

    //metodo para apagar usuario
    private function apagarUsuario($id)
    {
        try
        {
            // retorna true ou false de acordo com o sucesso
            return $this->crud->delete
            (
                "usuarios",
                "id = {$id}"
            );
        }
        catch(CRUDException $ex)
        {
            return false;
        }
    }
}
```

**entrar.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Leonardo Vilarinho
 * Date: 10/03/2016
 * Time: 00:59
 */

// inclui arquivo do template (o inicio da pagina)
include_once 'template/header.php';

// se tiver erro armazena numa variavel o erro do Controller em um painel vermelho
$printErro = (isset($erro))
    ? "<div class='text-danger text-center'><strong>{$erro}</strong></div>"
    : "";

?>
    <section class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4 col-md-offset-4">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <form method="post">
                    <div class="panel-heading">
                        <strong><?php echo $titulo; ?></strong>
                    </div>
                    <?php echo $printErro; ?>
                    <div class="panel-body">
                            <input name="nome" required  placeholder="Usuário" type="text" class="form-control"/>
                            <input name="senha" required placeholder="Senha" type="password" class="form-control" />
                            <!-- informa formulario a ser enviado desta página e quando ele foi enviado -->
                            <input name="login-requerido" value="1" type="hidden" />
                    </div>
                    <div class="panel-footer">
                        <input value="Entrar" type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" />
                    </div>
                </form>
            </div>
        </div>
    </section>

<?php
// inclui fim do template
include_once 'template/scripts.php';
include_once 'template/end.php';
```

**listar-usuarios.php**

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: Leonardo Vilarinho
 * Date: 10/03/2016
 * Time: 14:16
 */

// inclui arquivo do template (o inicio da pagina)
include_once 'template/header.php';

?>
    <section class="row">
        <div class="panel text-right">
            <a class="btn btn-primary" href="index.php?ato=novo-usuario" ><i class="fa fa-plus"> Novo</i></a>
        </div>

        <div class="col-md-12">
            <table class="table table-responsive table-bordered table-hover">
            <!-- cabeça da tabela -->
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>ID</th>
                        <th>Nome</th>
                        <th>Ação</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>

                <?php
                // enquanto tiver item na lista do metodo listarUsuarios do controller
                for($item = 0; $item < count($lista); $item ++)
                {
                    /*
                        botao editar tem um ato de editar-usuario e o id do usuario a editar

                        o botao apagar chama um javascript de confimação e o botao sim chama o ato
                        apagar-usuario e o id do usuario

                    */
                    echo <<<ITEM
                <tr>
                    <td>{$lista[$item]['id']}</td>
                    <td>{$lista[$item]['usuario']}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a class="btn btn-warning" href="index.php?ato=editar-usuario&id={$lista[$item]['id']}" ><i class="fa fa-pencil"></i></a>
                        <a class="btn btn-danger apagar" id="{$lista[$item]['id']}" ><i class="fa fa-trash"></i></a>

                        <div class="text-right oculto confirmacao{$lista[$item]['id']}">
                            <span>Deseja realmente excluir?</span>
                            <a class="btn btn-danger nao" id="{$lista[$item]['id']}" >Não</a>
                            <a class="btn btn-success" href="index.php?ato=apagar-usuario&id={$lista[$item]['id']}" >Sim</a>
                        </div>
                    </td>
                </tr>
ITEM;
                }
                ?>
            </table>
        </div>
    </section>

<?php
//inclui scripts do template
include_once 'template/scripts.php';

//adiciona script somente a essa pagina
echo "<script src='js/excluir-usuario.js' type='text/javascript'></script>";

//inclui final do template
include_once 'template/end.php';
```

A dúvida é como por exemplo expandir, criar um crud de notas por exemplo sem ter que colocar no `ControllerLogin` e `ModelLogin`. Ou seja, criar novas classes para outros objetos sem ser usuários (login). E se essa maneira que usei é correta?

Download do projeto: [arquivo login.zip](https://mega.nz/#F!glJBSLxT!YdOWqHmH0V7R9MYbg5VkiA)

Comment: Não entendi bem qual o ponto da dúvida. Você quer destrinchar o model?

Comment: A dúvida é como expandir o sitesma. Atualmente tenho o modelLogin, viewLogin e controllLogin.. Como expando colocando por exemplo notas dos usuarios, o certo seria criar um modelNotas, viewNotas e controllerNotas. Mas não sei como implementar em arquivos distintos. No caso eu teria de criar um  controller universal para distribuir o fluxo do ato entre os outros controllers?

Comment: E se estou inplementando da maneira certa, se é que há uma maneira certa

Comment: Acho que o que você procura está mais para *HMCV*. Também pode criar módulos tipo *widgets*, alguns frameworks possuem exemplos que podem servir como base pra você.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Amigo, você esta indo em um raciocinio bem, para clarear um pouco mais, a ideia é tirar todo e qualquer codigo estrutural, e viabilizar tudo em orientação a objeto como você pode fazer isso?

Primeiramente você tera que trabalhar com navegação get, via Classe e Metodo, por exemplo: index.php?c=classe&m=metodo, depois claro você pode organizar essa URL para uma URL amigavel.

o seu index.php seria mais ou menos assim:

```
include 'CoreController.php';

$core = new CoreController();
```

com o CoreController mais ou menos assim:

```
class CoreController {
    private $instance;        

    public function __construct() {

        $classe = $_GET['c'];
        $metodo = $_GET['m'];

        if(isset($classe) && $classe != '') {
            $this->instance = new $classe();
            if(isset($metodo) && $metodo != '') {
                $this->instance->$metodo();
            } else {
                $this->instance->index();
            }
        } else {
            $this->instance = new MainController();
            $this->instance->index();
        }

    }
}
```

O `$instance` é o controller carregado, nele você reproduz o conteúdo desejado, e carrega o model desejado como você fez com ControllerLogin e ModelLogin

Para melhorar, você pode criar metodos adicionais no CoreController, para verificar se os GET passados são validos, se existe o controle requisitado no $_GET['c'], se existe o método no controle requisitado, etc. Você pode trabalhar com passagem de argumentos para o método também, incluído mais variáveis GET na sua requisição.

Toda validação de conteúdo, como por exemplo, verificar se o usuário esta logado ou não, deve ser feita diretamente no seu Controller e não na index como no seu exemplo. Se ele esta navegando no ControllerLogin para exibir um conteúdo logado, mas ele não esta logado, esse controler deve ser capaz de redirecionar ele para outro controler para fazer o login, ou para exibir conteúdo disponível para usuário anonimo (não logado)

No meu exemplo, você pode redirecionar através da própria URL simplismente passando o controler e o metodo via GET.

Comment: Sobre POO eu discordo, não precisa ser inteiramente orientado, isso é modismo.
Agora a visão de como passar o ato foi boa, assim evita muitas verificaçoes como eu estava fazendo. Vou editar colocando um jeito modificado, passando a classe e o método no mesmo parametro.. embora eu ache meio inseguro passar esses dados por get. E sobre a verificaçao de sessao realmente seria no Controller. Obrigado

Comment: Bom, sobre Orientação a Objeto você pode dizer que é modismo agora, mas se um dia você tiver um big projeto em execução, você sentira o peso que uma orientação a objeto pode fazer em questão de manutenção do código, alem do mais, é sempre bom você manter seu POO em dia, isso vai lhe ajudar a abstrair mais conhecimentos e vai fazer diferença na concorrência em uma vaga de emprego.

Comment: Sobre a segurança depende da forma como você ira fazer os tratamentos de seu get, como eu disse em minha resposta, você pode criar métodos de validação dos paramentos gets na classe CoreController e pode garantir que todo Controller especifico requisitado já esteja com a segurança garantida dos GETs pelo CoreController, caso contraio você nega a solicitação do Controller pedido no GET no próprio CoreController.

Comment: Lembrando que todo e qualquer acesso sempre vai passar primeiro pelo o CoreController antes de chegar ao Controller especifico da requisição.

Comment: Digo porque é praticamente inútil  ter uma classe view, pois é muito raro ter um método na view, mas vai do gosto.
 Entendi o trabalho da Core, digo meio inseguro por exibir os nomes das classes e metodos no link. Mas é só a sensação mesmo pois pensando bem não atrai tantos problemas

Comment: Entendo, você pode partir do principio de nomear todas as suas classes Controller de acordo com o conteúdo a ser exibido e tirar termos técnico no nome da classe, como exemplo, você quer levar o usuário para alterar a senha, você teria uma classe controller chamada `Conta` e um método nessa classe chamada `AlterarSenha` a URI algo como: `index.php?c=Conta&m=AlterarSenha`, se você deixar isso com URL Amigável ficaria algo como: `index.php/Conta/AlterarSenha`